# Array reversal in C language using while loop

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, reverse

I made this program to reverse an array but it only works when I put in an odd number of digits in the array. If I put in even number of digits it doesn't print anything.
For example: If I put `{1,2,3,4,5}` the program will print `{5,4,3,2,1}` but if the input is `{1,2,3,4}` it doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, *arr, i, count;
    count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    arr = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
        count++;
    }
    
    int l_Count, h_Count, temp;
    temp = 0;
    h_Count = count - 1;
    l_Count = 0;
    while (l_Count != h_Count) {
        temp = *(arr + l_Count);
        *(arr + l_Count) = *(arr + h_Count);
        *(arr + h_Count) = temp;
        h_Count--;
        l_Count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line. More debugging tips here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Based on the description (not a look of the code), that sounds like an out of bounds error. `-fsanitize=address` should find this easily. Update: [yup](https://godbolt.org/z/1P47d7b9K)

Comment: The amount of effort spent on this code avoiding actually advancing *pointers* is sort of breathtaking. And there is utterly useless activity to boot (ex: what is `count` really used for? A synonym for `num` ?). Also, consider what can happen when the number of elements is *even*. Won't an ascending low counter and descending high counter eventually reside next to each other, then pass each other, thereby never tripping the *very* specific `l_Count != h_Count` condition ?

Comment: `while(l_Count != h_Count)` --> `while(l_Count < h_Count)`

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you have an index out of bounds error.

---

Using `-fsanitize=address` immediately confirms this.

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000020 at pc 0x000000401360 bp 0x7ffe26e3f5d0 sp 0x7ffe26e3f5c8
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000020 thread T0
    #0 0x40135f in main /app/example.c:21
    #1 0x7f3912c3f0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
    #2 0x4010fd in _start (/app/output.s+0x4010fd)

0x602000000020 is located 0 bytes to the right of 16-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000020)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f3912ec531f in malloc (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xbb31f)
    #1 0x401282 in main /app/example.c:9
    #2 0x7f3912c3f0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

[snip]
```

It even tells us which line the immediate cause of the problem is found (line 21).

---

Adding

```c
fprintf(stderr, "Swapping %d and %d.\n", l_Count, h_Count);
```

gives

```
Swapping 0 and 3.
Swapping 1 and 2.
Swapping 2 and 1.
Swapping 3 and 0.
Swapping 4 and -1.
```

So we found the immediate cause of the problem: The array has no elements at index `4` or `-1`. The program should have stopped after swapping `0` and `3`. Why didn't it? As homework, the fix is left to you.

Answer (score 0):

In this while loop

```
h_Count = count - 1;
l_Count = 0;
while(l_Count != h_Count)
{
    temp = *(arr + l_Count);
    *(arr + l_Count) = *(arr + h_Count);
    *(arr + h_Count) = temp;
    h_Count--;
    l_Count++;
}
```

when the number of elements is even (let's assume that it is equal to 2) then after these statements in the loop

```
    h_Count--;
    l_Count++;
```

h_Count never will be equal to l_Count.

You could rewrite the loop for example like

```
h_Count = count;
l_Count = 0;
while( l_Count < --h_Count )
{
    temp = *(arr + l_Count);
    *(arr + l_Count) = *(arr + h_Count);
    *(arr + h_Count) = temp;
    l_Count++;
}
```

If you want to use pointers in the loop the  it can look the following way

```
int *first = arr;
int *last  = arr + num;

while ( first < --last )
{
    temp     = *last;
    *last    = *first;
    *first++ = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic array reversal:

```
void *reverseArray(void *array, const size_t nelemets, const size_t elemsize)
{
    if(array && nelemets && elemsize)
    {
        unsigned char *last = (nelemets - 1) * elemsize + array;
        unsigned char *first = array;
        while(first + elemsize < last)
        {
            unsigned char temp[elemsize];
            memcpy(temp, first, elemsize);
            memcpy(first, last, elemsize);
            memcpy(last, temp, elemsize);
            first += elemsize;
            last -= elemsize;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    reverseArray(a, 5, sizeof(a[0]));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```